# C Duplicates in array

Tags: c, arrays, duplicates

So lets say i have an array of ints (max being its maximum size)

```
array = { 1, 7, 22, 3, 7, ... }
```

and i need to find a way to count the duplicates of each element in the previous array into another array like this one

```
duplicates = { { 1, 2 times }, { 7, 3 times } ...}
```

i know the syntax is wrong i just wanted to exemplify my goal (hope i expressed myself well enough) .. i have been thinking and i cant think of a way to do this (maybe it's simple but im kinda new at this) so i decided to post here for some guidance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using `C` not `C++`? It would much easier to write this in `C++`..

Comment: Can you explain what you're having trouble with?

Comment: i'm having trouble even starting.. like what should i do? i though about making like an auxiliar bidimensional array only with UNIQUE ints from the inicial array, and the count of duplicates it has (initialized at 0) and then for each one see how many times it exists on the original array.. what do you think? i'm thinking this isnt the easiest nor optimal array thats why i chose to ask here

Comment: You could sort the array so the duplicates will be one after the other.

Comment: Simplify the problem as "count how many times a given number is contained in an array". Once you have solved that, reuse that solution for an array of numbers. The solution won't be efficient (O(n^2)) but it's the easiest approach.

Comment: If you know the integers are into a known range and MAX is the maximum value an integer could be, you could also create an array[MAX] initailised with 0 values and with a scansion of the original array do `while(i<dim) array[original_array[i++]] ++;`

Comment: If you sort it first, the algorithm will be O(n*log(n)) (i.e., the performance of the sorting algorithm). Once the array is sorted, producing the array of duplicates is O(n). For the duplicates array, you can define a structure containing two fields, the number itself and the number of occurrences in the original array. You can malloc that array to have the same number of elements as the original array, which is the most you would need.

Comment: As an alternative to sorting, you can do it with a hash, which could give you even better performance.

Comment: @Andy Schweig: how to hash can help to solve this task? Sort and find duplicates is only preffered solution when we have integers between -MAX_INT to +MAX_INT.

Comment: Using the sorting method is fine and straightforward. A hash function allows you to maintain a key/value mapping where lookups (ideally) require constant time (O(1)). Your key would be the number and the value would be the number of occurrences. After going through the original array and updating values in the hash, you would go through all values in the hash to create your output array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory wasting does not cause any trouble in your case:

Define a struct

```
struct DuplicationInfo{
   int number;
   int times;
}
```

Then you can do a loop as follow

```
DuplicationInfo[max] duplicates;
// Initialze the array
for(int i=0; i < max; i++)
{
    duplicates[i].times= 0;
    duplicates[i].number = -1; // Any invalid number which you know is not in your array
}

for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
   // Look if the number is still in our duplicates list
   for(int j=0; j<max;j++){
       if(duplicates[j].number == array[i])
       {
           duplicates[j].times++;
           break;
       }
       else if(duplicates[j].number == -1)
       {
           duplicates[j].times= 1;
           duplicates[j].number = array[i];
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Let's compile this example with max = 2^32 ;)

Comment: I know. As I said its only suitable for not that huge arrays.

Comment: I see, your historgam method is suitable only for not wide ranges, but the author have -MAX_INT to +MAX_INT.

Comment: @AnatolyS then you should add a new boolean member in the struct.

Answer (score 4):

You could sort the array, maybe with an algorithm like `qsort` and then with a `for` or a `while` loop you can count how many times each element appear into the array since the duplicates will be one after another.

If you're under mac/linux type in the terminal `man 3 qsort` to see how it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could either sort the array in order to have the duplicates of a number just after the number and count them with a wile or you could use a structure with a number and frequency field. Each time you have to insert a new number into the array, if it is already into the array you just increase by one the frequency field.